# How can I find out the system default currency symbol on BlackBerry?

Tags: java, blackberry, currency

Is it possible to programmatically find the default currency symbol for the current locale in BlackBerry?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about BlackBerry limitations, but you should try this:

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency().getSymbol()
```

Comment: NumberFormat doesn't exist on BlackBerry. There is a Formatter class with a method called formatCurrency(), even. But it only works for the neutral Locale, which isn't very useful. Hence, this question: I have to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible to programmatically find the default currency symbol for the current locale in BlackBerry.

Please find this link:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-get-default-currency-value-from-BB-device/m-p/511079/highlight/false#M103418